How to create df2 file from database using C# core?
I am getting the data from databse . From database the data I am getting has 45 cols and 72 rows. In DFS 2 file should be 5 cols and 9 rows. 72 row means 72 hrs. The problem is every thing is fine but the file also creating but the values  am binding are not correct . because the before i had created a dfs2 file in python which is correct data. but when I am matching the data after creating the dfs 2 file using c# the values are not similar . SO i want to know that am i binding the data correctly for c#?
Here is the reference i took from
https://github.com/DHI/MIKECore-Examples/blob/master/Examples/CSharp/ExamplesDfs2.cs#L204
CreateDfs2File
This is my code
DataTable ecmwfWsData = new DataTable();
NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sqlSelectQuery, connection);
NpgsqlDataAdapter adp = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(cmd);
adp.Fill(ecmwfWsData);

string[] itemNames =
{
    "ECMWFC0000Ctrl", "ECMWFC0001Ctrl", "ECMWFC0002Ctrl", "ECMWFC0003Ctrl", "ECMWFC0004Ctrl",
        "ECMWFC0100Ctrl", "ECMWFC0101Ctrl", "ECMWFC0102Ctrl", "ECMWFC0103Ctrl", "ECMWFC0104Ctrl",
        "ECMWFC0200Ctrl", "ECMWFC0201Ctrl", "ECMWFC0202Ctrl", "ECMWFC0203Ctrl", "ECMWFC0204Ctrl",
        "ECMWFC0300Ctrl", "ECMWFC0301Ctrl", "ECMWFC0302Ctrl", "ECMWFC0303Ctrl", "ECMWFC0304Ctrl",
        "ECMWFC0400Ctrl", "ECMWFC0401Ctrl", "ECMWFC0402Ctrl", "ECMWFC0403Ctrl", "ECMWFC0404Ctrl",
        "ECMWFC0500Ctrl", "ECMWFC0501Ctrl", "ECMWFC0502Ctrl", "ECMWFC0503Ctrl", "ECMWFC0504Ctrl",
        "ECMWFC0600Ctrl", "ECMWFC0601Ctrl", "ECMWFC0602Ctrl", "ECMWFC0603Ctrl", "ECMWFC0604Ctrl",
        "ECMWFC0700Ctrl", "ECMWFC0701Ctrl", "ECMWFC0702Ctrl", "ECMWFC0703Ctrl", "ECMWFC0704Ctrl",
        "ECMWFC0800Ctrl", "ECMWFC0801Ctrl", "ECMWFC0802Ctrl", "ECMWFC0803Ctrl", "ECMWFC0804Ctrl"
};

if (ecmwfWsData.Rows.Count == 0)
{
    return $"Data is not present for FRDate: {frDate} and FRun: {fRun}";
}
else
{
    double x0 = 79.89999974583402;
    double y0 = 12.500001526228607;

    string[] dfsCoordinate = { "LONG/LAT", x0.ToString(), y0.ToString(), "0" };
    double dfsDx = 0.1;
    double dfsDy = 0.1;
    int dfsDt = 3600;

    var fDTime = "";
    var frdate = $"{frDate.Substring(0, 4)}-{frDate.Substring(4, 2)}-{frDate.Substring(6, 2)}";
    DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(frdate);

    if (fRun.Equals("R00"))
    {
        fDTime = date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy 06:30:00");
    }
    else if (fRun.Equals("R06"))
    {
        fDTime = date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy 12:30:00");
    }
    else if (fRun.Equals("R12"))
    {
        fDTime = date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy 18:30:00");
    }
    else if (fRun.Equals("R18"))
    {
        date = date.AddDays(1);
        fDTime = date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy 00:30:00");
    }

    // the start time based on FDTime
    DateTime dfsstarttime = DateTime.ParseExact(fDTime, "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    double[,,] ecmwfGridData = new double[72, 9, 5];
    int ni = 0;

    foreach (DataRow row in ecmwfWsData.Rows)
    {
        int columnIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                ecmwfGridData[ni, i, j] = Math.Round((double)Convert.ToDouble(row.Field<float>(columnIndex)), 1);
                columnIndex++;
            }
        }
        ni++;
    }



    DfsFactory factory = new DfsFactory();
    Dfs2Builder builder = Dfs2Builder.Create("ECMWFGridData", "dfs Timeseries Bridge", 0);

    // Set up the header
    builder.SetDataType(1);
    builder.SetGeographicalProjection(factory.CreateProjectionGeoOrigin("UTM-33", 12.438741600559766, 55.225707842436385, 326.99999999999955));
    builder.SetTemporalAxis(factory.CreateTemporalEqCalendarAxis(eumUnit.eumUminute, dfsstarttime, 0, 60));
    builder.SetSpatialAxis(factory.CreateAxisEqD2(eumUnit.eumUmeter, ecmwfGridData.GetLength(2), 0, dfsDy, ecmwfGridData.GetLength(1), 0, dfsDx));
    builder.DeleteValueDouble = -1e-30;

    // Adding custom block
    // M21_Misc : {orientation (should match projection), drying depth, -900=has projection, land value, 0, 0, 0}
    builder.AddCustomBlock(factory.CreateCustomBlock("M21_Misc", new double[] { 327, 0.2, -900, 10, 0, 0, 0 }));

    // Set up dynamic items
    foreach (var item in itemNames)
    {
        builder.AddDynamicItem(item, eumQuantity.Create(eumItem.eumIRainfall, eumUnit.eumUmillimeter), DfsSimpleType.Double, DataValueType.Instantaneous);
    }

    string dfsfilename = Path.Combine($"D:\\DFS2", $"AllWSDFS_{frDate}_{fRun}_CtrlFile.dfs2");
    // Create file
    builder.CreateFile(dfsfilename);

    // Get the file
    Dfs2File file = builder.GetFile();

    // Loop over all time steps
    for (int i = 0; i < 72; i++)
    {
        // Loop over all items
        for (int j = 0; j < itemNames.Length; j++)
        {
            // Create item data from the provided data array
            IDfsItemData2D<double> itemData2D = (IDfsItemData2D<double>)file.CreateEmptyItemData(j + 1);

            // Transpose the 2D array
            double[,] transposedData = new double[ecmwfGridData.GetLength(2), ecmwfGridData.GetLength(1)];
            for (int k = 0; k < ecmwfGridData.GetLength(2); k++)
            {
                for (int l = 0; l < ecmwfGridData.GetLength(1); l++)
                {
                    transposedData[k, l] = ecmwfGridData[i, l, k];
                }
            }

            // Create a 1D array of the expected data type
            int totalElements = transposedData.GetLength(0) * transposedData.GetLength(1);
            double[] data = new double[totalElements];

            // Copy data from transposedData to the 1D array
            int index = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < transposedData.GetLength(0); k++)
            {
                for (int l = 0; l < transposedData.GetLength(1); l++)
                {
                    data[index++] =  Math.Round(transposedData[k, l], 1);
                }
            }

            // Write the 1D array to the file
             file.WriteItemTimeStep(j + 1, i, 60, data);
        }
    }
    file.Close();


Can you be more specific than just saying "not correct"? What do you expect and what do you get instead?

I have edited my question. I just  want to know that  I am binding the data in a correct way or not ?
